# Visual Studio Regex help

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I am using regex in Find/Replace in VS IDE. I need to replace the string `message="My message"` in all aspx files with an empty string. The html looks like this

```
<input id="test" message="My message"/>
```

I am trying to use the regex to find for `message="{.*}"` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try message="{[^"]*}"

Answer (score 1):

Because * is greedy it will capture until it finds the **last** quote, instead of the **next** quote, which is what you want. By telling the expression to capture all non-quote characters, you can ensure that it only captures up to the next one.

message="{[^"]*}"

Answer (score 0):

use message="[^\"]*"

You can test your regex queries live on the nregex site - http://www.nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx